# City boundary for Fort Lauderdale, Florida

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, government, city

Where can I find data for the boundary of Fort Lauderdale, Florida? I'd like to load the data into [carto.com](https://carto.com/) to create a map.

I looked on their [gis website](http://gis.fortlauderdale.gov/), but I couldn't find an outline of the city itself.

Comment: openstreetmap.org is always a good place to check first, though the answers below appaer better.

Comment: @BarryCarter Thanks for pointing that out. I will check their in the future. Unfortunately they don't seem to have the kind of boundary data I'm looking for. I searched for Fort Lauderdale, which it found, but without the boundary.

Comment: I'll doublecheck, but they should have everything TIGER/LINE has plus lots more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get political boundaries from the [Florida Geographic Data Library](https://www.fgdl.org/download/).

Use the metadata tool: under content choose "Admin & Political Bounds", then scroll down to, for example, "CITY LIMITS - DERIVED FROM FLORIDA PARCEL DATA - 2015"

here's the [metadata overview](https://www.fgdl.org/metadataexplorer/full_metadata.jsp?docId=%7BE53F7AAA-9D33-4175-B10D-4C4307F3C79F%7D&loggedIn=false)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can download from the [TIGER Geodatabases](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html) page. Under `Download State Level Geodatabases` choose Florida, and then in the `Incorporated_Place` layer find the row with `NAMELSAD = 'Fort Lauderdale city'`. It looks like this, which I think is fairly accurate:

[image: ft-lauderdale from TIGER]

Comment: Was this map created using ESRI? What is the format of the data?

Comment: Please see the first paragraph on the linked page: `TIGER Geodatabases are spatial extracts from the Census Bureau’s MAF/TIGER database for use with Esri’s ArcGIS. However, Open Source GIS such as QGIS also support the Geodatabase format.`